# How to detect if elements are ready in #each helper in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

How to detect if elements are ready in #each helper in emberjs?
An Em.View has didInsertElement, but #each doesn't... For some reasons, I don't want to use a Em.CollectionView

```
<ul>
  {{#each App.users}}
    <li>
      {{name}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>def</li>
  <li>ghi</li>
</ul>
```

when:

```
App.set('users', [{name:'xyz'},{name:'opq'}])
```

I want to do something when '<li>xyz</li>' and '<li>opq</li>' are ready.

I think using a Em.View in #each is too complex in such a simple case like this.

Comment: Can you explain what "ready" means in your context and what you want to do then?

Comment: I actually had the same problem because I wanted to run isotope over the list every time my list changed & when it was completely rendered.  I don't have a good solution but I ended up making a Mixin that did a deferred call to the parent when it was attached/changed (it actually was a bit more complex; it made sure the parent view even has the correct method, skip virtual parents, kept a counter on the parentView so the method would only be called once if there were a bunch of changes... but you get the general idea).  That was back in 9.8.1... One of first things I did in ember actually.

Comment: Niels Hoffmann: I mean the moment the <li> elements have been inserted to DOM.

Comment: It would certainly be worth knowing what reasons you have for not wanting to use a CollectionView.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> For some reasons, I don't want to use a Em.CollectionView

But that is exactly what the solutions is:

```
App.ListItemView = Em.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        do your stuff...
    }
});

App.ListView = Em.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    itemViewClass: App.ListItemView,
});
```

Is there an actual technical reason for not wanting to use a CollectionView?